# SQL newbie needs to know what is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

Just started playing with MySQL and I've already made stupid mistake which is somewhere in there; that's what I need to figure out:

```
CREATE TABLE `txts` (
 `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `name` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
 `content` VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
 `lastupdate` DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It gives:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX) NOT NULL,
`lastupdate` DATE NOT NULL default '0000-00-00', PRIMARY KEY ' at line 4
```

I know it's extremely stupid but I can't see a single mistake in it.

Comment: Apparently, you can't use MAX in `VARCHAR(MAX)`; that's what the error message is saying.  You may need to check your version of MySQL vs the [manuals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html).

Comment: No MAX in MySQL, use a fix number.

Comment: Can you please mention which version of MySQL you are using?

Answer (score 7):

```
VARCHAR(MAX)
```

MySQL does not support the use of `MAX`.

Use an real number value.

Per Google:

> The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.